# How to set statistics level of a table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, statistics

I know how to set statistics level for a particular column i.e

```
alter table table_name alter column column_name set statistics 100;
```

However, if I wish to set statistics level for a particular table or for a particular schema, is there is one liner command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing ready-made for a table or schema, because that is seldom useful.

But you can set it for a whole database with

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET default_statistics_target = 1000;
```

You can also use `psql`'s `\gexec` to set the statistics target for all columns of a table:

```
SELECT format(
          'ALTER TABLE %s ALTER %I SET STATISTICS 1000',
          attrelid::regclass,
          attname
       )
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = 'pgbench_tellers'::regclass
  AND attnum > 0 \gexec
```

Comment: Thank you Laurenz